# XamlParseException stopping project

Tags: constructor, performancecounter, xamlparseexception, invocation

I am learning C# 2010 using the book 'Microsoft VS C# 2010 Step by Step' whose Chapter 27 introduces the Task Parallel Library. When I run the provided 'GraphDemo' project, I get an XamlParseException error.
I went over several of the threads on this site on the same exception and managed to drill down the inner exception to a failure to load the PerformanceCounter.
Fearing corruption of my system's .NET Framework 4 installation, I repaired it to original state but the error persists.
The strange thing is that, none of the other readers of the book have complained about this issue; after I wrote to the publishers, the author asked me to send him a zipfile of the project and he claims it ran fine on his machine. There are seven other projects in Chapter 27 and all of them throw the same error on my system.

This the full text of the exception generated:

```
System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException was unhandled
  Message='The invocation of the constructor on type 'GraphDemo.GraphWindow' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception.' Line number '3' and line position '5'.
  Source=PresentationFramework
  LineNumber=3
  LinePosition=5
  StackTrace:
       at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.RewrapException(Exception e, IXamlLineInfo lineInfo, Uri baseUri)
       at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(XamlReader xamlReader, IXamlObjectWriterFactory writerFactory, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlObjectWriterSettings settings, Uri baseUri)
       at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.LoadBaml(XamlReader xamlReader, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlAccessLevel accessLevel, Uri baseUri)
       at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.LoadBaml(Stream stream, ParserContext parserContext, Object parent, Boolean closeStream)
       at System.Windows.Application.LoadBamlStreamWithSyncInfo(Stream stream, ParserContext pc)
       at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Uri resourceLocator, Boolean bSkipJournaledProperties)
       at System.Windows.Application.DoStartup()
       at System.Windows.Application.<.ctor>b__1(Object unused)
       at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
       at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
       at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
       at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(Object userData)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
       at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
       at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
       at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
       at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.InvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
       at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
       at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
       at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
       at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
       at System.Windows.Application.Run(Window window)
       at System.Windows.Application.Run()
       at GraphDemo.App.Main() in E:\IT Books\Source Code Projects\Microsoft Visual C# 2010 Step By Step\Chapter 27\GraphDemo\GraphDemo\obj\x86\Debug\App.g.cs:line 0
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException: System.InvalidOperationException
       Message=Cannot load Counter Name data because an invalid index '' was read from the registry.
       Source=System
       StackTrace:
            at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterLib.GetStringTable(Boolean isHelp)
            at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterLib.get_NameTable()
            at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterLib.get_CategoryTable()
            at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterLib.CounterExists(String category, String counter, Boolean& categoryExists)
            at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterLib.CounterExists(String machine, String category, String counter)
            at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter.InitializeImpl()
            at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter..ctor(String categoryName, String counterName, String instanceName, Boolean readOnly)
            at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter..ctor(String categoryName, String counterName)
            at GraphDemo.GraphWindow..ctor() in E:\IT Books\Source Code Projects\Microsoft Visual C# 2010 Step By Step\Chapter 27\GraphDemo\GraphDemo\GraphWindow.xaml.cs:line 25
       InnerException: 

And this is the code pinpointed by the inner exception:

    public GraphWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        PerformanceCounter memCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Memory", "Available Bytes");
        availableMemorySize = Convert.ToUInt64(memCounter.NextValue());
        this.pixelWidth = (int)availableMemorySize / 20000;
        if (this.pixelWidth < 0 || this.pixelWidth > 15000)
        this.pixelWidth = 15000;
        this.pixelHeight = (int)availableMemorySize / 40000;
        if (this.pixelHeight < 0 || this.pixelHeight > 7500)
        this.pixelHeight = 7500;
    }
```

Line 25 is the one where memCounter is initialized.

I shall appreciate all the help I can get.

Answer (score 0):

There is a good chance you are referring to a .Net 2.0 application while targeting the 4.0 framework. Try adding **useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true"** to the config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and here is how I solved.
Basically, your Performance Counter list is corrupted.
http://blogs.technet.com/b/yongrhee/archive/2009/10/06/how-to-rebuild-performance-counters-on-windows-vista-server2008-7-server2008r2.aspx

To solve this:
Run CMD as Administrator, and on the command prompt enter:

C:\Windows\System32\lodctr /r

The performance counters will be rebuild from scratch.